# Prove that $\{1, 11, 1001,\dots\}$ is an irregular language

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

Let $L:=\{1, 11, 1001,\dots\}$ be the language with alphabet $\{0,1\}$ which is formed by all powers $3^n, n=0,1,\dots$ written in binary notation. How to prove that $L$ is not regular?

Comment: what are you allowed to use? can you use the pumping lemma?

Comment: and another thing, 101 in binary is 5, it's not a power of 3^n, same for 1111, which is 15

Comment: @ user1067083 :Thank you. A hard day's night. It has been fixed. Yes, but which version do you mean? A direct proof is preferable in view of teaching.

Comment: see my answer i'll be glad to recieve feedback

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pumping lemma is your friend as it states that if $L$ were regular, there'd be a length $n$ such that all $w\in L$ with $|w|>n$ can be split into $w=xyz$ with $y\ne\epsilon$ such that $xy^kz\in L$ for all $k\in\mathbb N_0$. We do not know $n$, but consider one such word $w$ and let $a,b,c$ be the numbers represented by the binary strings $x,y,z$ and let $N_k$ be the number rpresented by $xy^kz$.
Then $$N_{k+1}=(N_k-c)\cdot 2^{|y|}+b\cdot 2^{|z|}+c$$
and as $N_k\to\infty$ (because $x$ begins with a $1$), we have $\frac{N_{k+1}}{N_k}\to 2^{|y|}$ as $k\to\infty$. On the other hand, $\frac{N_{k+1}}{N_k}$ is always a power of $3$. Thus for sufficiently big $k$, we find $m$ with $|3^m-2^{|y|}|<\frac12$, i.e. $3^m=2^{|y|}$. This is only possible if $m=|y|=0$, contradicting $|y|\ne 0$.

Comment: I have changed my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Use the pumping lemma:

Assume in contradiction that $L$ is regular, so any word $w$ in $L$ longer than $n$, can be divided into $w=xyz$ such that:

1. $y$ is not empty word
2. $|xy| \le  n$
3. and for each $k$, the word $xy^kz$ is in $L$ too.

Now, let $n=3$, and $w=1001$ such that $x = \emptyset, y=100$ and $z=1$. Take $k = 2$, we'll get a new word $w' = 1001001$, which is in binary $73$, which is NOT in $L$.

It's the second time I give an answer, I'll be glad to have a feedback from the others.

Comment: How about the pumping length? Up to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#General_version_of_pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages) , the one  exists. As far as I understand it, this means we cannot take an arbitrary value $k$.

Comment: As far as I understood wiki, you can choose a k too show that for that k, the condition doesn't hold. and because it has to be for every k, L is irregular

Comment: @user1067083 Try to use $\LaTeX$ in your answers.

Comment: i'll be glad to have a guide for usage of latex in the website @Kaster. thanks for the edit

Comment: @user1067083 [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) source looks good to me.

Comment: To prove that a language is regular, you can pick the pumping length $k$; to prove the opposite you have to do it for all $k$.  Hence this solution is, sadly, incorrect.

Comment: @vadim123 I appericiate the feedback. you're welcome to edit my solution then...

Comment: Not only that, but you can't pick how to divide $w$ into $xyz$, you have to check for all divisions satisfying properties 1. and 2.

Comment: I have changed my mind.

Comment: Fine. Hope you will get the help you deserve

Comment: @user67083: Vote up is mine.